# Oracle apex 19.1 display image error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle19c

I am trying to display an image in oracle apex 19.1 which is saved as a `LONG RAW` in the database column.

I have created a new page with a new region.

This is the select sql query in the region as a classic report.

```
select ID,
       PHOTO
  from MY_TABLE
  where "ID"= '1'
```

I have changed the type for the PHOTO column as Display Image and in the BLOB Attributes -> BLOB column it shows as `varchar2` instead of `LONG RAW`

And when I run the application I see the following error:

```
report error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, please don't use the datatype `LONG RAW` anymore, use `BLOB` instead. It is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT613) since a couple of decades. (I believe the only reason it's still there is that Oracle uses `LONG` to store views and defaults.)

EDIT:

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm#i1006094), migrating `LONG` to `LOB` is actually quite easy. Here is a minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, x LONG RAW);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, RPAD('a', 2000, 'a'));
```

The table can be migrated to `BLOB:

```
ALTER TABLE told MODIFY (x BLOB) LOB (x) STORE AS SECUREFILE;
```

Comment: Can I change the datatype in the existing production database? And if not then is there a way to use a function is APEX?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can change the datatype in an existing database. Does this answer your question?